# I'm trying to sort the netlist error in proteus

Tags: pic, proteus

I'm simulating pic in Proteus loaded the hex file of the Proteus but I'm getting the following error:

[image]
[image]

Also I am getting the error of MQ-2 sensor library saying ".......\users\zain\appdata" not found (this library downloaded from The engineering projects.

Answer (score 1):

On Proteus, you need to configure your power rails.

Go to Design -> Configure Power Rails

[image]

Then create the power rail and set the voltage. Select the power rail and click add to add it to the power rail.

[image]